# Cross product and matrix of rotation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for simplify the following equation and extract vector $\omega$ to the right side.

$(R\cdot x)\times(R\cdot(\omega\times x))$

where $\times$ is the three-dimensional cross product, $x$ and $\omega$ are three-dimensional vector, and $R$ is a rotational matrix.

Thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean by extract $\omega$ to the RHS? You only have an expression, not an equation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Using index notation and Einstein sum rule

$$\#_i=\varepsilon_{jki}R_{j\ell}x_\ell R_{km} \varepsilon_{npm}\omega_nx_p$$

Beside switching $\omega\times x$ to $-x\times\omega$ I can not see a huge simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x\neq 0$, otherwise not much can be said. Then by factoring its norm, we can suppose $x$ has norm 1. Let $v$ be the vector in your statement. Then $R^{-1}v=x\wedge (\omega\wedge x)=x\wedge(\omega_\bot \wedge x)$ where $\wedge$ is the cross product and $\omega_\bot=\omega- x (x\cdot \omega)$.

This shows that you will be able only to extract information on the component of $\omega$ which is orthogonal to $x$, that is, the solution is modulo multiples of $x$. Note also that $|\omega_\bot|=|v|$. So assuming $v\neq0$ (the solution otherwise being the multiples of x), we have $R^{-1}v/|v|=x\wedge(u\wedge x)$ where the unit vector $u$ is unknown, but is orthogonal to x. So we can also assume $v$ has norm 1.

We arrive at the equation $R^{-1}v=x\wedge (u\wedge x)$ for the unknown unit vector $u$ which is orthogonal to $x$. But then notice that for any two unit vectors $a$ and $b$, $a\wedge(b\wedge a)=b$; indeed, wlog, you can take them among the two first of the canonical basis (upon rotating them to achieve this, which you can since then the cross product will likewise be rotated). So finally, you conclude $u=R^{-1}v$.

Then read upward. I don't know if there's a short answer, sorry for the length thus.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explication ;) It helps a lot.

Comment: No problem, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Well, rotation applied to both operands of the cross product is the same as applying it to a whole. So

$$(R\cdot x)\times (R(\omega\times x))=R(x\times (\omega\times x))=$$
$$=R(|x|^2-x\otimes x)\omega$$
or with indices
$$=R_{ij}(|x|^2 \delta_{jk}-x_jx_k)\omega_k$$
The thing that multiplies $\omega$ is simply a new matrix, a product of rotation and projection to the plane perpendicular to $x$ (with som additional scaling, of course).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your simplification.